# LOB storage parameter query

Tags: oracle11g, storage, clause, lob

This is for Oracle 11

I created a table by running a script like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."Table12" (
    "Column1" CLOB
)
PCTFREE 0
PCTUSED 0
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
LOB("Column1") STORE AS (TABLESPACE "TEMP"
STORAGE (INITIAL 65537)
ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW
CHUNK 8193
PCTVERSION 11
CACHE
LOGGING);
```

Now, I am trying to run queries to obtain the values of storage parameters of Column1.
I started with the tablespace name and I used

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME FROM ALL_LOBS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'Column1'
```

I was able to get the name successfully. I tried to obtain the value of "INITIAL" which is 65537; however, can't seem to find the right query to get it.

Please kindly advise.

Samir

Comment: What database is this??

Comment: Hi marc, it's Oracle 11.